# Retrieving last 11 months for chart

Tags: sql-server

I need the last 11 months with November and December as well as the current month for my chart but can not see the month when there is no data. And it's still called the last years that should not be.

```
declare @TempTable TABLE
(
[Order] int,
[Month] nvarchar(3),
[Booked] int,
[Cancelled] int
)

declare @CurrentYear int = cast(substring(convert(varchar, getdate(), 23), 0,5) as int)
declare @CurrentMonth int = cast(substring(convert(varchar, getdate(), 1), 0,3) as int)

insert into @TempTable 
select
(@CurrentYear - substring(convert(varchar, A.CreatedAt, 23), 0,5)) * 11 + 
@CurrentMonth - cast(substring(convert(varchar,A.CreatedAt, 1),0,3) as int)
as 'Order',
substring(convert(nvarchar, A.CreatedAt, 107), 0, 4) as 'Month',
Count(*) as 'Booked',
SUM(cast(A.IsCancelled as int)) AS 'Cancelled'
FROM ReservationTbl A
GROUP BY substring(convert(nvarchar, A.CreatedAt, 107), 0, 4),
(@CurrentYear - substring(convert(varchar, A.CreatedAt, 23), 0,5)) * 11 +
@CurrentMonth - cast(substring(convert(varchar,A.CreatedAt, 1),0,3) as int)



select * from @TempTable WHERE [Order] <> (SELECT MAX([Order]) FROM @TempTable) Order By [Order] DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Use a [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/).

Comment: How would that be relevant to OP Question?

Comment: @LowellEdLlames because the OP won't have any rows if there is no data for a specific month. One of the uses for a Calendar table is specifically for these cases. The article I've linked goes into far more detail; i suggest having a read if you're not familiar with them. Their a staple to most "good" SQL Environments.

Comment: JOIN with `(VALUES (0), (1), ..., (11))` to "generate" the dates.